# Encode 64, Ruby and Mandrill API

Tags: ruby, mandrill

I am trying to encode a file in Ruby before sending it as an attachment through the Mandrill API. I am getting the following error messages:

```
/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/base64.rb:38:in `pack': no     implicit conversion of File into String (TypeError)                                           
    from /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/base64.rb:38:in `encode64'                                                                                  
    from email_spreadsheet.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

The following is my ruby code:

```
require 'mandrill'
require 'csv'
require 'base64'
CSV.open("my_results.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["animal", "count", "price"]
  csv << ["fox", "1", "$90.00"]
end

my_file = File.open("my_results.csv")
my_file_encoded = Base64.encode64(my_file)

m = Mandrill::API.new
message = {  
 :subject=> "Hello from the Mandrill API",
 :from_name=> "Mandrill",  
 :text=>"Hi Gmail, how are you?",  
 :to=>[  
   {  
     :email=> "hello@gmail.com",  
     :name=> "Howie"  
   }  
 ],  
 :html=>"<html><h1>Hi <strong>Gmail</strong>, how are you?</h1></html>",  
 :from_email=>"mandrill@yourdomain.com",
 :attachments=>[
        {
          :type=> "file/csv",
          :name=> "my_results.csv",
          :content=> attachment_encoded
        }
    ]
}
sending = m.messages.send message
puts sending
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're handing a `File` instance to `Base64.encode64` when it expects a `String`. Hence the "implicit conversion" error. Read the file into a `String` first:

```
my_file = File.open('my_results.csv', 'r') { |fp| fp.read }
my_file_encoded = Base64.encode64(my_file)
```

or:

```
my_file = File.read('my_results.csv')
my_file_encoded = Base64.encode64(my_file)
```

You could also use [`CSV.generate`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-generate) to write your CSV straight into a `String` and skip the file altogether.

Comment: Getting there. It's now throwing the following error: `email_spreadsheet.rb:29:in "<main>": undefined local variable or method "attachment_encoded" for main:Object (NameError)`

Comment: Oh wow. Silly me. I inserted the wrong variable name. All good now. Awesome and thanks for your help!